# Jenkins + Nginx on my ubuntu server keeps redirecting to app_address:8080

Tags: nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I have one staging server for my application which hosts jenkins and my web app.

I'm using nginx and here's the jenkins.conf for it:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;
    server_name ci.myurl.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_redirect  http://127.0.0.1:8080 http://ci.myurl.com;
    }
}
```

The thing is, everytime I go to my browser and type: ci.myurl.com I get redirected to staging.myurl.com:8080 (my app is hosted at staging.myurl.com using port 80).

Everything works okay but I want jenkins to live at ci.myurl.com without redirections.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration works on my Jenkins:

```
upstream app_server {
   server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken." message with that configuration

Comment: I updated nginx config. There was missing bracket '}'. But I assume that wasn't the cause of the problem. Maybe the following link will help you: http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/running-jenkins-behind-nginx/ , https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy

Answer (score 0):

you should check Jenkins's configure  " Jenkins URL " is correct, it should be you server name "http://ci.myurl.com/"